# Multiselect in fabric js without key modifier

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I was wondering if there is a way to actively set multi-selection "mode" in fabric js canvas without holding down the shift?

I wish to activate multiselection by listening on a boolean value thats tied to a checkbox.

I have been reading through the fabricjs docs and haven't found anything regarding multi-select without the shift modifier key.

I'm uncertain if my request is valid but any pointers would be appreciated.

So basically I listen on the mouse:down event and checks if my boolean value is true/false, and if it's true i would like to go into multi-selection mode.

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', evt => {
  if(this.multiSelect) {
    // activate multi-select
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `selection:created` event and then push each new selection into an array that you will then use to create an `ActiveSelection` with multiple objects. When you set `this.multiSelect` to false you will need to also empty the `multiSelection` array. Something like this:

```
var multiSelection = [];
canvas.on('selection:created', selected => {
  if(this.multiSelect) {
    multiSelection.push(selected);
    var groupSelection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(multiSelection)
    canvas.setActiveObject(groupSelection);
  }
});
```